# How to configure grunt uncss on a php file?

Tags: php, gruntjs, uncss

I'm new to grunt, and I'm trying to learn it. 
It kind of simple if I have index.html file to deal with, but I don't have it, I have index.php instead - so I've tried :

```
uncss: {

    dist: {

        options: {

            ignore       : [/expanded/,/js/,/wp-/,/align/,/admin-bar/],
            stylesheets  : ['css/clean.min.css'],
            ignoreSheets : [/fonts.googleapis/],
            urls         : [],
        },

        files: {
            'css/clean.min.css': ['**/*.php']
        }
    }


},
```

---

Result

I keep getting

```
Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task
Fatal error: PhantomJS: Cannot open about:blank
```

---

Can someone please tell me what did I do wrong ?

I would really any helps or concern on this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by change the file type. convert (.php) file to (.html) file.
after uncss, delete (.html) file.